# Is there a way to smooth the polygonal aspect of AR Objects with ARCore Sceneform?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

The aspect of AR objects with Sceneform seems more polygonal than without (using OpenGL).

For my tests I have used ARCore samples [with](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/samples) and [without sceneform](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases) and for example with this [3D Object](https://poly.google.com/view/8KU4S7I0sL8).

Is there a way to smooth it ? Adding more light ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too poor. No details, no images, no reproducible code...

Asides bugs or implementation details on a library the most common case of "more polygonal aspect" is the [shading method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading) and interpolation techniques.

Check that sceneform (filament at the end) and your OpenGL implementation are using the same shading method.

Comment: Thank you, I have added details. The difference between the 2 renderings is well similar to the differences between Flat and Phong interpolations.